# Removing tracking references to remote that no longer exists

Tags: git, msysgit, git-extensions

My remote was named BitBucket and I decided to rename it origin, so I deleted BitBucket and created origin with the same URL as BitBucket.

Now I seem to have tracking references for both origin and the now-deleted BitBucket.  How do I get rid of the tracking references for BitBucket?

I've seen lots of references online to pruning but that seems to only work with a remote that still exists.  How do I clean out references to branches in a remote that no longer exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rename/delete a remote reference, all remote tracking branches would be renamed or deleted too.

So try and rename `origin` to `BitBucket` (to get back to the initial state):

```
git remote rename origin BitBucket
git fetch BitBucket
```

(That should make sure you have only the remote '`BitBucket`' tracking branches)

*Then* rename the remote `BitBucket` into `origin`:

```
git remote rename BitBucket origin
```

And check if the remote tracking branches `remotes/BitBucket/xxx` have been renamed in `remotes/origin/xxx`.